# Catch Fatal error in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to catch error when invalid data to `imagecreatefromjpeg` are passed. Cake php displays error page saying `Fatal Error Cake\Error\FatalErrorException` so this code supposed to work but it is not:

```
            try {
                $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
            } catch (\Cake\Error\FatalErrorException $e) {
                echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            }
```

I'm also tried to use `\Exception`, `\Cake\Core\Exception\Exception`, `\ErrorException` but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

`imagecreatefromjpeg()` normally shouldn't cause fatal errors, but only warnings, you may want to investigate that further.

Anyhow, catching fatal errors via `try...catch` is only possible as of PHP 7, where most of them have been changed to exceptions. You'd have to catch `\Error` or `\Throwable` in that case. However there are still fatal errors that cannot be catched, for example when `require()` fails, or memory is exceeded.

`\Cake\Error\FatalErrorException` is being created internally in a regular error handler, where (uncatched) fatal errors will be handled, ie that exception is not being thrown, and therefore cannot be catched.

See also

- **[PHP Manual > Language Reference > Errors > Errors in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php)**
- **[PHP Manual > Language Reference > Predefined Exceptions > Error](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php)**
- **[PHP Manual > Language Reference > Predefined Interfaces and Classes > Throwable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php)**
- **[CakePHP Source > \Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleFatalError()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.5.4/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php#L214)**

Comment: Thank you for really useful answer. If interested you can easily replicate my case. Just pass ``.png`` image to ``imagecreatefromjpeg()``. You will see Fatal Error  
``Error: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50``. And no, \Error or \Throwable does not catching too.

Comment: @dMedia That's actually a bug, most likely this: **https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73116**. You may want to update your PHP installation and/or php-gd module. I do receive the same error as a warning: `$ php -r "imagecreatefromjpeg('test.png');"

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error:  in Command line code on line 1
Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): 'test.png' is not a valid JPEG file in Command line code on line 1`

Comment: I just upgraded to ``PHP 7.1.11-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 27 2017 13:49:56)`` and ``GD headers Version => 2.2.5
GD library Version => 2.1.1`` but still from ``php -r "imagecreatefromjpeg('test.png');"`` get ``PHP Fatal error:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50 in Command line code on line 1``

Comment: There's a version mismatch, guess your PHP was compiled with GD 2.2.5 (this is where the bug has been fixed), but the linked version is GD 2.1.1.

Comment: It seems that until now GD 2.2.5 not available in Ubuntu packages. I checked the latest. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/php7.1-gd/download. Uncertain what to do – wait, or try to compile..

Comment: You could try using `ondrej/php`: **https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php?field.series_filter=xenial**.

Comment: That is what I'm using to have php 7.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 ``php7.1-gd is already the newest version (7.1.11-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)``

Comment: Well, I'm afraid there's not much more I could say as I'm not overly familiar with nix systems. I'm using `ondrej/php` too and it installed the `2.2.5` version as expected.